# My API key has been revoked for 'reverse engineering' the API? I followed docs closely

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

I requested more quota and after months of back and forth YouTube decided to revoke my API key for 'reverse engineering' the API. I am not intending to reverse engineer anything and followed the developer policies closely. My app is described at https://playsiv.com

Can anyone help guide me as to how to open a line of communication with the API team so I can resolve their concerns and obtain the desired quota limit to launch my app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer: Please note the fact that I'm not a Google employee, neither am affiliated or connected in any way with this company; am only using its public APIs, as many others do.)

A first question that pops into my mind: are you using web-scraping over YouTube? That's forbidden by section III.E.6 of [DTOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies).

To my understanding, your app employing reverse engineering (if it actually does that; I cannot know) means that the app makes use of undocumented YouTube APIs. That's forbidden by section III.D.7 of DTOS.

A first look at [one of app's web page](https://playsiv.com/how-playsiv-works/) made me think that the app downloads video content from YouTube -- if it does not, I honestly misunderstood that page's descriptions. Downloading video content from YouTube does imply using undocumented APIs and, indeed, reverse engineering.

Comment: That helps. I am not downloading videos at all nor am I scraping, Everything I'm doing is straight from the documentation and developer policies. I will revise my descriptions since you're the second person to suggest the same two points.